# thinkster.IO tutorial Chapter 6 - 'Auth' not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I'm following along [This](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/wBhtRLWHIR/6-authenticating-users-with-a-service) tutorial and is now about to set up a simple authentication service. I'm getting an error message saying that:

*app\scripts\controllers\nav.js*

*line 15  col 5  'Auth' is not defined*

For some reason my nav.js file can't relate to my auth.js file or i'm I getting this wrong?

**controllers/nav.js**

```
'use strict';


app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post) {

$scope.post = {url: 'http://'};

$scope.submitPost = function () {
    Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref) {
        $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name());
    });
};

$scope.logout = function () {
    Auth.logout(); //HERE IS THE ERROR LINE
};

});
```

**controllers/auth.js**

```
'use strict';

app.controller('AuthCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Auth) {
if (Auth.signedIn()) {
  $location.path('/');
}

$scope.register = function () {
  Auth.register($scope.user).then(function (authUser) {
    console.log(authUser);
    $location.path('/');
  });
};
});
```

**services/auth.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Auth', function ($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) {
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

var Auth = {
  register: function (user) {
    return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password);
  },
  signedIn: function () {
    return auth.user !== null;
  },
  logout: function () {
    auth.$logout();
  }
};

$rootScope.signedIn = function () {
  return Auth.signedIn();
};
return Auth;
});
```

Comment: You forgot to inject the Auth service in your `navCtrl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the Auth factory into NavCtrl

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post, Auth) {
```

Comment: Awesome. I missed this too! Works 100% perfect now.